# symfony 3 curl_exec(): Unable to create temporary file

Tags: symfony

I am getting:

```
Warning: curl_exec(): Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory.
```

EDIT:
ERROR:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: curl_exec(): Unable to create temporary file, Check permissions in temporary files directory." at /data/web/virtuals/180989/virtual/www/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php line 40
```

I have tried to clear cache, to set some directories chmod 777, nothing changed.

Everything works perfectly until i uploaded my project on a hosting when I visit specific url it shows me an error.

What should i do with that?

Comment: Have you located where this curl_exec exists in the actual code in your project? Is it a part of Symfony framework or your code? And, even if you change the permission of a certain directory, if done without recursive option(-r), you might have failed to set that permission to a certain file this curl_exec tried to operate on.

Comment: is it part of bundle (i am using guzzle http client)

Comment: But since now i have no problems